# NET framework vs. SDK downloads

Tags: .net

Hi I'm trying to set up a build server for NET projects and am confused about certain things. I'm coming from a Java background so need to know the difference in the NET packaging strategies.

As far as I'm aware, the `framework` is equivalent to the JRE in Java, while the `NET SDK` is equivalent to the Java SDK. Is this correct? Because, when I search for the `Net SDK` the framework pages are shown, and (from the [Net 4.0 Framework download page](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17718)), it states that *'The Microsoft .NET Framework 4 redistributable package installs the .NET Framework runtime and associated files that are required to run and develop applications to target the .NET Framework 4'*.

Also, as it's a cloud based build server, I want to keep the amount of crap I install to a minimum, and the SDK ISO is over a Gb in size (hope it only installs selectively).

PS. I know this question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300089/confused-about-net-redistributable-packages-and-sdk), but I'm still confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET framework is, in a sense, both the redist and SDK. You only need to install the .NET framework and MSBuild.

If you want to do some .NET development, then you should get a copy of Visual Studio. It includes all of the .NET development tools that you would expect an SDK to have.

I would also like to point out that you probably want the .NET Framework 4 Full, rather than Client Profile. This is the full framework, whereas CP is the cut-down version for smaller apps.

Comment: What's the SDK then? BTW, I don't want to do development on this machine. I'm configuring it to pull code from SCM, build it, and email reports around. Development will occur on other machines.

Comment: There's no real SDK for .NET, it's just the .NET framework. The tools that you'd expect to come with an SDK (e.g. `ilasm`, `ildasm`, `rc`, etc) just come with Visual Studio. You don't need it for just running .NET applications.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to install the .Net framework and then use MSBuild on your build server.

E.g. c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>MSBuild c:\Sandbox\MySolution.sln